# Firebase Firestore list of all IDs in a collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Google Firebase seems to be difficult to wrap my head around... I have no problems in getting documents and their data out of a collection, but when I try to simply get a list of all the IDs inside a collection, I am not able to figure out what the call should look like. I have tried searching for the info, but without success.

[image]

I have a function declared in my service component, which looks like this:

```
getCollRegistrationNumbers(): firebase.firestore.CollectionReference {
  return firebase.firestore().collection(`storedItems`);
}
```

Then in e.g. the Search page of my app, I am calling the function from my component, but whatever I try, it returns empty.

Given the service function above, how should I complete the code below to just git a list of the IDs?

```
this.fireStore.getCollRegistrationNumbers().get()
  .then(snapshot => {....})
```

Comment: Can anybody tell How we can query and get this middle collection/ids so we can query next subcollection by ids ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at how your documents are displayed in an italic font: this means, in the console, that these documents are only present as "container" of one or more sub-collection but that they are not "genuine" documents.

Comment: Ok, so could I work around that, by writing some other (dummy) data directly into the "empty" containers? Or is that a silly idea?

Comment: Yes, that would be an option. You could also write your IDs array in one specific document in a dedicated collection (taking care of the Firestore limits, however: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields).

Comment: The "dummy" field option seems an easy one. If there is a dedicated collection for the IDs, that would require again extra code, and especially when deleting data, etc. Thanks for your reply!